# Out of time Timer5 interrupt Arduino

Tags: arduino

I have this code , I try to restart Timer5 when it out of time. But i can't, may you help me ?

```
#include <TimerFive.h>
#include <TimerOne.h>
#include <openGLCD.h>
#define OLDWAY
unsigned long timer5_started=0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Timer1.stop();
  Timer1.detachInterrupt();
  Timer1.initialize(500000);
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(Timer1Handle);  
  Timer1.start();

  Timer5.stop();
  Timer5.detachInterrupt(); //detach interrupt
  Timer5.initialize(100000);
  Timer5.attachInterrupt(Timer5Handle);  
  Timer5.start();
  ///---

}

void loop() {
  while(1){
    Serial.println("loop...");
    delay(500);
  }
}
void Timer5Handle(){    
    timer5_started=millis();
    Serial.println("timer 5...");
    while(1){
      int a=0;
    }
}
void Timer1Handle(){    
    if(millis()-timer5_started>100000){
      Serial.println("restart...");
      Timer5.restart();
    }
}
```

When Timer5 out of time, the Interupt is stop, how can i restart it ?
When Timer5 out of time, the Interupt is stop, how can i restart it ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't even understand what are you trying to do in that interrupt handler:

```
void Timer5Handle(){    
    timer5_started=millis();
    Serial.println("timer 5...");
    while(1){
      int a=0;
    }
}
```

However your interrupt handler is called in actual IRS, so everything else stops including all other Interrupts (including `millis` counting and `delays`). And because of infinite loop, it's forever. Interrupt handler should be as short as possible to ensure others are not missed or so.

Comment: Thank for answer KIIV, But i control a Graphic LCD on interrupts, When LCD have errors it just like  while(1){}, it loop forever, How can i reset when error happen ?, if not my Board stop running...

Comment: To be clear: you use Timer5 as a watchdog (even there is a hardware one, and it can reset whole cpu when it overflows), and you wan't to stop doing anytning by infinite loop. And you're asking how to reset countdown in that Timer5 if nothing wrong happen?